# Documentation about Rinternals's "VECTOR_SEXPREC"

Tags: r

In Rinternals.h, `VECTOR_SEXPREC` `struct` is defined as:

```
typedef struct VECTOR_SEXPREC {
    SEXPREC_HEADER;
    struct vecsxp_struct vecsxp;
} VECTOR_SEXPREC, *VECSEXP;

where

struct vecsxp_struct {
    R_len_t length;
    R_len_t truelength;
};

#define SEXPREC_HEADER \
    struct sxpinfo_struct sxpinfo; \
    struct SEXPREC *attrib; \
    struct SEXPREC *gengc_next_node, *gengc_prev_node

typedef union { VECTOR_SEXPREC s; double align; } SEXPREC_ALIGN;
```

and it is said that the two last pointers in SEXPREC_HEADER are "used to maintain the colector's linked list structures". Unlike the SEXPREC struct, where node data seems to be represented as the u union member of the struct, in this one I can't see which of it's members represent the 'node data'.

The `DATAPTR(x)` (which is the data access macro) is defined as:

```
#define DATAPTR(x)  (((SEXPREC_ALIGN *) (x)) + 1)
```

where it seems that the data correspond to the pointer following x, but I don't understand how does this work. Is there any documentation where this is clearly explained?  (I've already searched in R internals but i haven't found very much )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The aptly named [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) manual discusses SEXP objects in [Section 1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs).

Comment: Yes, but I thought that perhaps there existed something else about this topic.